# Baixar uma imagem do Jira com com nodejs utilizando autorização

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagem, jira

Boa tarde, preciso baixar uma imagem de perfil do Jira via REST. Eu até consigo, mas o jira me manda uma imagem referenciando que não possuo autorização de vê-la (exemplo de como a imagem é baixada: [imagem](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTU-Df6AI2tQw1f-aPOE2zsdUckY6p3qltMCswXwm53af8yk4nP))

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const request = require('request')
const app = express()
const download = require('download')

app.use(cors())

function callApiUserPhoto(callback){
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `url/rest/api/2/user/search?username=user` , 
        auth: { username: "user", password: "senha" },
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if(response.statusCode != 200){
            return callback('error');
        }else{
            download(JSON.parse(body)[0].avatarUrls['48x48'], 'dist')
            return callback(JSON.parse(body)[0].avatarUrls['48x48'])
        } 
    })
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    callApiUserPhoto(function (response) {
      if (response == 'error') {
        res.send("ops")
      } else {
        res.send(response)
      }
    })
  })

app.listen(4000, console.log("Sever online!"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução!
Passei uma request com autorização(sem a url) dentro do else

```
const options2 = {
      method: 'GET',
      auth: { username: user, password: senha },
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    };
      request(JSON.parse(body)[0].avatarUrls['48x48'], options2).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${user}.png`));
```